# How to iterate controls to get their value in a loop in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have many controls in an activity layout in Android, and
i want to get their value in a simple for, the problem is that 
Eclipse assigns the ID randomy, so I cannot get controls ID in a 
sequential way to access the controls in a for loop because
they are not sequential IDs.

Here is why I am trying to do:

```
int visibleId = R.id.fieldVisible1;
int editId = R.id.editField2;
int spinnerId = R.id.spinner1;

for(int nIndex = 0; nIndex < 12; nIndex++)
{

CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(visibleId + nIndex);
checkBox.setChecked(_fieldsInfoArray.get(nIndex).getVisible() == 1);

EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(editId );
edit.setText(_fieldsInfoArray.get(nIndex).getName());

Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(spinnerId + nIndex);
spinner.setSelection(_fieldsInfoArray.get(nIndex).getOffset());
}
```

how can I make Eclipse to assign sequential IDs to controls so I can 
just increment by 1 the id in a loop?

Comment: Can you put the ids in an array and index through that?

Comment: Yes I could, but I was trying to see if it was possible to get sequential Ids for a range of controls, because, now I have 12 controls of three different types of each, what would happen if there were 30 controls of each type? Try typing the Ids in an array....

Answer (score 0):

A better way of doing this may possibly to look into the use of:

```
int children = layout.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < children; i++){
  View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
}
```

This would allow you to loop over all views inside the layout without needing to know their IDs.

Comment: mmm I never thought of that, but how ouwl I know what control would I be refering to? the position is importatn, because echa control value, depending on the position goes to a database table in a specific row,

Comment: I'm not sure why you would ever need to loop over views unless you are adding them programatically but you could identify each view by setting its tag.